# TypeScript: Preventing overlap in union members

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type which is a union of many union strings.

ex.

```
type SubUnion1 = "one" | "two"
type SubUnion2 = "two" | "three"
...
type SubUnionN = "nine" | "ten"

type Union = SubUnion1 | SubUnion2 | ... | SubUnionN
```

I would like TS to throw an error if any of the sub-unions have overlapping strings.  In this example, `SubUnion1` and `SubUnion2` overlap on `"two"`, which should throw an error.

I am aware that this can be done between 2 types using something like:

```
type NoOverlap<A, B> = Extract<A, B> extends never ? A & B : never
```

However, I cannot think of a graceful way to do this will more than 2 types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you consider this approach "graceful", but at least it doesn't require that you write out every pair of `SubUnionX` elements yourself:

First make a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of the sub-unions so that the compiler can deal with them programmatically before you put together `Union` and lose track of the different sub-unions:

```
type SubUnions = [SubUnion1, SubUnion2, /* ... */ SubUnionN]
```

Then we can make a type which evaluates to `never` if there are no overlaps, and otherwise it produces a union of tuples with information about where the overlaps are:

```
type Overlaps<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: { [L in keyof T]:
    L extends K ? never :
    (T[K] & T[L]) extends never ? never :
    ["Elements at indices", K | L, "both contain", T[K] & T[L]]
}[number] }[number]
```

Essentially we're [mapping over the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) twice to make an N-by-N matrix.  We look at each element with index (`K`,`L`), and if `T[K]` and `T[L]` overlap, then we put an entry in the matrix.  Then we get all the entries in the matrix as a union.

Note that the entry `["Elements at indices", K | L, "both contain", T[K] & T[L]]` is technically just a tuple type with four elements.  The first and third elements are string literal types, and the second and fourth are the overlapping key and overlapping property types respectively.  This type is really not useful as the type of any *value* at runtime.  We're not thinking of making a four-element array that looks like this.  It's really just something laid out in a way that we hope will produce a useful error message.  In other words, it's a makeshift ["invalid type"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) (a feature that doesn't currently exist in TypeScript but may eventually be implemented as something like [`throw` types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40468)).

Finally if you want an actual compiler error if there are overlaps, we can make a type function that only accepts `never`.

```
type ExpectNever<T extends never> = void;
```

Finally we put that all together like this:

```
type EnsureNoOverlapsOfSubUnions = ExpectNever<Overlaps<SubUnions>>; // error!
// Type '["Elements at indices", "0" | "1", "both contain", "two"]' 
// does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.
```

Hopefully that error message is enough to help fix the problem.

Oh, and if you have `SubUnions` as a tuple, you can get your original `Union` by just getting its `number`-indexed properties:

```
type Union = SubUnions[number];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwKoDsCWB7FBGKBeKAIiwkKgB8jgB3DQgKFElkVUxQCZ8razLDgACwBOEUvQD0EqADo5jcNHjJ0WAHLdC6FKQpUIKBgubK2WAM7cA2qdU4ANCxXsOjiQCpZcqO+m32agC6UPTG0ADyAG4QwgA2AIZg5gA8ACpQEAAewAYAJpbxKCBWgQB83ADeUFYA0lBoKFAA1hAgGABmUKmBAFxQVVYAMvWNLW2d3T30UDNQw1k5KPlQdQD8UDrRwlB9ABSptcEAZF1DgQCUGdl5lpsxUOt3231WhACisRAAtgbABcAjXJoADGEHMhEcdUog0chAQGCEUGBWGA8QaENONWOp0GgUC9AAvlYUHAvggYsEiSSyRTQkxoG9MpBgcA1BAtmkrotlk9ygRIhg0LkANx0xRQN4ocxwURqDBRGIJJLhdr+CzcRnM1nsmLJBVxRIpNVS0qlYVQKQZYTCDDCACEkmkqXFAHJXh9vr9-oCQWCMYQAAx8IjYf3wxHIlCo9Gwmh0QIukKW3IYMEbBFQczxYBocztEBQITQSPmYDCNFRqAup4umRi5hmRoEY3mYmk8nCQKi+hAA)

Comment: One small request actually! Would you be able to point me to documentation for what is happening in this line? `["Elements at indices", K | L, "both contain", T[K] & T[L]]` This is something I didn't know was possible!

Comment: I added some info about what that is.  It's a type that fakes up an error message.  The compiler thinks "this is a tuple type of four elements" but hopefully when a human reads the message in their IDE they interpret `["Elements at indices", "0" | "1", "both contain", "two"]` as a single string like `"Elements at indices 0 and 1 both contain 'two'"`.